# typescript export sub-modules without "dist" folder

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a simple module `modA`:

```
modA/
- package.json
- dist/
  - index.js
  - db.js
  - stuff.js
```

I'd like to be able to use the submodules "db" and "stuff" like this: `import * as db from modA/db` -- how can I do that? I have `main: dist/index.js` in my `package.json` but that doesn't set `dist/` as a default for submodules, so the only way I can get it to work is `import * as db from modA/dist/db` (explictly including the "dist" in the import). `import * as db from modA/db` just gives the "Cannot find module" error.

The `dist` is there because I'm compiling from typescript.

In case it's important, I want this to work in node.js and browser, where I'm using webpack.

As an alternative, can I add some kind of namespace re-export code in `index.js` to make this work?

Comment: I'd also be happy with `import db from modA`, exporting all the things in `db.ts` as `db` somehow -- any help?

Comment: Hey where are you importing these modules  .....

Comment: @Supercool. This is a workspace in a yarn monorepo, so I'll be importing them into other typescript files in different workspaces in the same repo. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yea did you try my solution?

Comment: Going to try it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make following import work

```
import * as db from 'modA/db';
```

In tsconfig.json  add paths like below

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "modA/*": [
        "dist/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Ref: https://indepth.dev/configuring-typescript-compiler/